# Need help reading from a data file into different variable types in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

Okay so I've been having a lot of trouble with my code as it does not work.
I am trying to read from a data file like this
//example of a data file I'd be attempting to read from - comments aren't part //of the file
9569.99 //a double that only occurs once in the file

Yukon //string- Name of car (1)

red //string- color of car (2)

400 //double- price of car (3)

Huehue // (1)

hehe // (2)

60 // (3)
//end of file

This is how I am attempting to read through it and it is not working in the slightest. How might I change this code so that it might actually work as intended? Thanks!

```
ifstream myfile(menu_file);

    double file_bal;
    string file_carName;
    string file_carColor;
    double file_carPrice;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile >> file_bal;
        cout << "I HAVE READ IN THE BALANCE FROM THE FILE!\n";
        bal = file_bal;
        //
        string line;
        int x = 1;
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            istringstream ss(line);

            if (x == 1)
            {
                ss >> file_carName;
                x++;
            }
            if (x == 2)
            {
                ss >> file_carColor;
                x++;
            }
            if (x == 3)
            {
                ss >> file_carPrice;
                x++;
            }
            if (x == 4)
            {
                Car c(file_carName, file_carColor, file_carPrice);
                addCar(list, c);
                x = 0;
            }


        }
```

Comment: `myfile >> file_bal;` ? or ` myfile << file_bal;`

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream myfile(menu_file);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    double file_bal;
    myfile >> file_bal;
    cout << "I HAVE READ IN THE BALANCE FROM THE FILE!\n";

    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        string file_carName;
        getline(myfile, file_carName);

        string file_carColor;
        getline(myfile, file_carColor);

        double file_carPrice;
        myfile >> file_carPrice);

        Car c(file_carName, file_carColor, file_carPrice);
        addCar(list, c);
    }
}
```